# Year date range input in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

Does anyone know how to do year range input (to choose the years such as 2013-2023) in reactjs. I have tried with react-year-range-picker. But this doesnot work

Answer (score 1):

To create a year range input in React, You can use `react-year-range-picker` module. However, this module requires some peer dependencies such as `styled-components` so you need to install this module like this:

```
npm i react-year-range-picker styled-components --legacy-peer-deps
```

This code works fine:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { YearRangePicker } from "react-year-range-picker";

const App = () => {
  const [yearRange, setYearRange] = useState({
    startYear: 2010,
    endYear: 2020,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Year Range Picker</h1>
      <YearRangePicker
        minYear={2000}
        maxYear={2030}
        onSelect={(startYear, endYear) => {
          setYearRange({ startYear, endYear });
        }}
        startYear={yearRange.startYear}
        endYear={yearRange.endYear}
      />
      <p>
        Selected Years: {yearRange.startYear} - {yearRange.endYear}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```